# Missing value often results in errors in lapply (in R)

Tags: r

I got errors in this code:

```
FUN = function(files) {
  df_week<- data.table::fread(files)

#Sun rate
for (i in 1: nrow(df_week) ){

#check if df is not NA
if(!is.na(df_week[i])) 
{
    if(df_week$Sun[i] >=10 ) {df_week$Sunr[i] =5}
        ....
 }
}

files = list.files(pattern="1_Stas*")

lapply(files, FUN)
```

Output:

> Error in if (!is.na(df_week[i])) { : argument is of length zero
> In addition: Warning message:
> 13 failed to parse.

Why does the code `if () {}` gives errors?

If the input contains missing value or NA, the ouput should be NaN or NA , and `lapply` should continue to the next list of files.

I have tried it with a single file without using `lapply` and function, the output appears in the environment as empty data.

So when I do it one by one, there's no error. When it is done using `lapply`, very often there would be problems. Should I uses for loop instead?

Any suggestions to fix it and make `lapply` continue to the next list of files when the previous file contains missing value?

Thanks.

Comment: my recent solution by put this: 
if(nrow(df_week)>0) { ...

it solve 1st file but for other file with nrow() >1 and NA inside 
error again in :

if(df_week$Sun[i] >=10 ) {df_week$Sunr[i] =5}

Error in if (df_mon$Sun[i] >= 10) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: why inside lapply,  if () with missing value becomes a big problem

Comment: Why not lapply gives NA when deal with NA data
and not asking why input is NA

Comment: What do you mean `#check if df is not NA`? Do you want to check if a row of `df` is all NA's or just one element?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop. The `apply` family is good for quick one-liners when you need to apply a single operation to one dimension of your data. Your code will become:

```
files = list.files(pattern="1_Stas*") 
df_week <- data.table::fread(files) # Make sure length(files) == 1

#Sun rate
for (i in 1:nrow(df_week)) {
    #check if df is not NA
    if (!is.na(df_week[i])) {
        if (df_week$Sun[i] >= 10) {
             df_week$Sunr[i] = 5
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The line containing `if(!is.na(df_week[i])) {` needs clarification. From context, `length(dim(df_week)) > 1`, so you probably want

```
if (all(!is.na(df_week[i]))) {
...
}
```

`all(!is.na(df_week[i]))` returns true when the `i`th row of `df_week` containes no NA values.